# Is IndexedDB duplicating local files to store for an offline application?

Tags: firefox, indexeddb

Firefox only allows access to full file path via [extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145622/firefox-extensions-and-full-file-paths-from-html-form)

It has also been stated that if you store files in IndexedDB that they are stored externally, outside the DB (see [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/))

<s>If I insert a bunch of files into IndexedDB, close it down, come back tmw and open the DB, how does it know where my files that I inserted yesterday are located?</s>

Does IndexedDB have access to the full file path? If so, can I get access to the full file path via InexedDb?

OR does IndexedDB make duplicate copies?

(this is for offline use)

**EDIT**
I can store a bunch of files with their own separate keys in IndexedDB and iterate over them to repopulate an application.

IndexedDB is smart enough not to store the same copy of the file.  How does it do this?

Most importantly, if the application is an image viewer for offline use then importing those images into IndexedDB to be managed will duplicate the files(?)  Now I have two sets of vacation photos.  Is this correct?

Comment: why you need full file path, if you can get the file by its key?

Comment: The files can have their own key but then it comes down to duplicating many photos to reside next to the IndexedDB.  If given access to the full file path then no duplication needs to occur.  I just store the file path and when I load the viewer the images are loaded.

Comment: Also, recall that IndexedDB is smart enough to detect if you are trying to store the same file (internal reference counter).  How does it do this?

Comment: I think he does this by looking at the raw data of the image. If that binary data is an exact copy, it will assume that it is the same data so it will only keep one file with multiple references

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that these files will get stored at the same location where the indexeddb databases will be located. For more information where to find it, take a look at [my post](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2011/11/indexed-db-deleting-your-database.html) I wrote about the location of the indexeddb some time ago

Comment: But imagine if I had over 100 photos that you wanted to store on IndexedDB.  They would all get duplicated and put next to the db?  That's a little extreme, no?

Comment: If you read the article you provided, they say the save the file outside the indexeddb, but Mozilla is smart enough to save only one copy of the file if it is referenced multiple times. The AppData folder is the only where Mozilla is storing data in.

Comment: Thank you for your response and article.  I did read it.  But I still think it's a bit extreme.  If I build an image viewer for offline use to view my vast collection of images and I want to use IndexedDB to store the images (and other meta that I may add ie. tags, etc) I would assume wrong to think that I can store the file paths in the DB, rather than duplicate one copy of the file to reside outside the DB in the folder.  So now I have a copy in my 'vacation' folder and another outside the indexedDB.

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about that. How the indexeddb saves the files on the file system is the responsibility of the browser. You will always get the raw data back as a blob, even if the indexeddb stores a reference to a file in the back.